# Drawing double hline with longtabu

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu, longtabu

I'm trying to draw a double horizontal line with `longtabu`

```
\begin{longtabu}{|l |l |}
\hline
0 & 1\\
\hline \hline
1 & 0\\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

... however, all I get is a thick line.

When using `tabu`, everything works as expected.

How should I proceed so as to get a double horizontal line using `longtabu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the package `hhline` solved my problem.

```
\begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 0\\
\hhline{==}
0 & 1\\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
```